# Scroll bar is not visible in windows application

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms

I am working on 3 windows applications which are built in VB. Last week I got an OS (windows 10) update which updates the build (version 1909 Build 18363.1500) of the system. After this update the scroll bars of all 3 applications in the Datagrid got invisible.

I tried to upgrade the framework to higher version but still it is not working.

[image: Application Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely the result of Microsoft update KB5001337 being installed in Windows 10 1909.  See [April 13, 2021—KB5001337 (OS Build 18363.1500)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/april-13-2021-kb5001337-os-build-18363-1500-e7336837-2aaa-4f73-995c-ab2ba5013727), the "Known issues in this update" portion of that page.

According to that 'known issue', "Microsoft is working on a resolution and will provide an update in an upcoming release."

Until Microsoft fixes this, from other reports on the 'net about this problem, uninstalling KB5001337 will restore the scroll bars.

Running a later Windows release (eg, 20H2) does not seem to incur the problem, so another option is to upgrade Windows.

**Edit - Workaround**

(credit to Jimi for pointing this out in a comment)

At least for Winform impacted applications, it appears that specifying the dependency on v6 of the Common Controls library will bring the scroll bars back.

In the application manifest, add (or uncomment) the dependency for Commmon Controls.  Should look at least similar to this:

```xml
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Glad to have helped.  If this does answer your problem, please consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: @Jimi - thank you for pointing out the manifest update.  I had not seen this during my own research and effort to address this for our own apps and clients.